# Reversing a singly linked list in C++: pointer in the stack

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory

I have a single linked list made up of Nodes, a class with 2 members:

```
Node* next;
int val;
```

The list is as follows:

```
[head:0] -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> nullptr
```

I wrote a function to reverse this list.

```
void reverseList(Node* head) {
    Node* m = head->next;
    head->next = nullptr;
    
    while (m) {
    Node* n = m;
    
    m = n->next;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
    printNode(head);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Create linked list here

    reverseList(&head);

    cout << "FXN ENDS" << endl;

    printNode(&head);
}
```

This will print:

```
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0
FXN ENDS
0
```

I know that `Node* n` gets deleted once `reverseNode` is exited, since `n,m` are allocated on the stack. But by setting `head=n;` shouldn't the memory that `n` points to still be in the heap even after the function is exited and hence `head` still points to valid memory?

Thank you.

Comment: You could have used a debugger and found that out in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that Node* n gets deleted once the While loop is exited, since n is allocated on the stack. But by setting head=n; shouldn't the memory that n points to still be in the heap even after the While loop is exited and hence head still points to valid memory?

Pointers are just like variables, when it comes to passing them to functions. The default behavior is to *copy* the pointer. If you actually want to change the argument passed to the function, you need to take it by reference:

```
void reverseList(Node* &head) {
```

Comment: But even if a pointer is copied, the address it points should be the same address no?

Comment: Yes, the address it points to is the same, but the pointer itself is not. So while modifying `head->next` would change it in `main`, modifying `head` will not.

Comment: @John, Another way is to return the pointer, but that is professionaly not a good idea

Comment: I see it makes sense now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @John If the answer answers your question, then consider accepting it.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 *professionaly not a good idea* requires a lot of riders to clarify when it's bad. In this case I mostly agree with you because the list is being modified--the caller's not getting a new list--but too many people read a blanket statement like that and march into Cargo-Cult Land.